# GDB front-end for stm32 debugging

Tags: atom-editor, stm32, gdbserver

Currently I'm debugging my stm32 via st-linkv2 with st-util and arm-none-eabi-gdb tools.

- I launch st-util as server for gdb on port 4242.
- I lanch arm-none-eabi-gdb as client on the same port.

This work well and I can debug with the classic gdb command line.

I'm looking for a front-end interface on atom editor.

I tried several package from atom:

- dbg with client/server configuration
- dbg-arm-none-eabi-gdb

nothing worked as expected

Is there a solution to have front-end debugger inside atom for remote target device?

Comment: "nothing worked as expected" Could you clarify your expectations?

Comment: Switch to vscode and use cortex-debug extension.